`Segmentation fault (core dumped)` encountered in Ubuntu 20.04 when using `pip install`
I'm using the nuplan_devkit and following the installation documentation below.
cd && git clone https://github.com/motional/nuplan-devkit.git && cd nuplan-devkit
conda create -n nuplan python=3.9
conda activate nuplan 
pip install -e .
pip install -r requirements_torch.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt

After creating the virtual environment in conda with conda create -n nuplan python=3.9, I need to install all the dependencies with pip install -r requirements.txt and pip install -r requirements_torch.txt. However, it keeps randomly throwing Segmentation fault (core dumped) during the process. For randomly I mean it occurs in different stages per trial when I ran the command repeatedly.
Here's an example failure when installing pytorch with pip install torch==2.0.1 torchvision==0.15.2 torchaudio==2.0.2
Collecting torch==2.0.1
  Downloading torch-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (619.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 619.9 MB 72 kB/s 
Collecting torchvision==0.15.2
  Downloading torchvision-0.15.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (6.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 6.0 MB 15.9 MB/s 
Collecting torchaudio==2.0.2
  Downloading torchaudio-2.0.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (4.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 4.4 MB 9.7 MB/s 
Collecting nvidia-nccl-cu11==2.14.3
  Downloading nvidia_nccl_cu11-2.14.3-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (177.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 177.1 MB 384 kB/s 
Collecting nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.5.0.96
  Downloading nvidia_cudnn_cu11-8.5.0.96-2-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (557.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 557.1 MB 56 kB/s 
Collecting networkx
  Downloading networkx-3.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.6 MB 12.2 MB/s 
Collecting triton==2.0.0
  Downloading triton-2.0.0-1-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.whl (63.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 63.3 MB 6.9 MB/s 
Collecting nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11==11.7.101
  Downloading nvidia_cuda_cupti_cu11-11.7.101-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (11.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 11.8 MB 14.4 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in ./miniconda3/envs/nuplan/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torch==2.0.1) (4.12.2)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock in ./miniconda3/envs/nuplan/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torch==2.0.1) (3.16.1)
Collecting nvidia-cusolver-cu11==11.4.0.1
  Downloading nvidia_cusolver_cu11-11.4.0.1-2-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (102.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 102.6 MB 645 kB/s 
Collecting nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66
  Downloading nvidia_cublas_cu11-11.10.3.66-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (317.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 317.1 MB 8.2 MB/s 
Collecting jinja2
  Downloading jinja2-3.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 133 kB 13.7 MB/s 
Collecting nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11==11.7.99
  Downloading nvidia_cuda_nvrtc_cu11-11.7.99-2-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (21.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 21.0 MB 9.6 MB/s 
Collecting nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11==11.7.99
  Downloading nvidia_cuda_runtime_cu11-11.7.99-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (849 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 849 kB 13.0 MB/s 
Collecting nvidia-cufft-cu11==10.9.0.58
  Downloading nvidia_cufft_cu11-10.9.0.58-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (168.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 168.4 MB 19.1 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: sympy in ./miniconda3/envs/nuplan/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torch==2.0.1) (1.13.3)
Collecting nvidia-nvtx-cu11==11.7.91
  Downloading nvidia_nvtx_cu11-11.7.91-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (98 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 98 kB 7.1 MB/s 
Collecting nvidia-curand-cu11==10.2.10.91
  Downloading nvidia_curand_cu11-10.2.10.91-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (54.6 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 54.6 MB 8.9 MB/s 
Collecting nvidia-cusparse-cu11==11.7.4.91
  Downloading nvidia_cusparse_cu11-11.7.4.91-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (173.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 173.2 MB 4.7 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: pillow!=8.3.*,>=5.3.0 in ./miniconda3/envs/nuplan/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torchvision==0.15.2) (11.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./miniconda3/envs/nuplan/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torchvision==0.15.2) (2.32.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./miniconda3/envs/nuplan/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torchvision==0.15.2) (1.23.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./miniconda3/envs/nuplan/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66->torch==2.0.1) (59.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in ./miniconda3/envs/nuplan/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66->torch==2.0.1) (0.44.0)
Collecting lit
  Downloading lit-18.1.8-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 96 kB 9.3 MB/s 
Collecting cmake
  Downloading cmake-3.30.5-py3-none-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (26.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 26.9 MB 14.2 MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in ./miniconda3/envs/nuplan/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jinja2->torch==2.0.1) (3.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in ./miniconda3/envs/nuplan/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->torchvision==0.15.2) (3.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./miniconda3/envs/nuplan/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->torchvision==0.15.2) (2024.8.30)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in ./miniconda3/envs/nuplan/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->torchvision==0.15.2) (3.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in ./miniconda3/envs/nuplan/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->torchvision==0.15.2) (1.26.20)
Collecting mpmath<1.4,>=1.1.0
  Using cached mpmath-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (536 kB)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)


I tried different sources of pip and it doesn't help.
I tried remove and recreate the virtual environment
Also tried uninstall and reinstall pip/miniconda
I tried to manualy install each dependency in the requirements.txt， but even for a single package installation, I got the error sometimes as well. By multi-trial, sometimes it  is successfully installed by chance.

Could you please help me figure out the cause of this error and some suggestions on how to solve it?
